# Issues converting Adobe Ai and Psd files using Magick

Tags: c#, io, imagemagick, adobe

I'm using Magick to convert Adobe files (Pdf, Ai, Psd) to Png images and it all works fine except that the Ai files can take over a minute to convert and Psd files lose their shape when converted, as the layers are laid out side by side instead of overlaying each other. This is the code I am using..

```
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
settings.Density = new Density(300);
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    images.Read(file, settings);
    using (MagickImage horizontal = images.AppendHorizontally())
    {
        file = path + "\\" + ThumbnailFolder + "\\TempThumb.Png";
        horizontal.Write(path + "\\" + ThumbnailFolder + "\\TempThumb.Png");
    }
}
```

Are there changes I can make in the Settings to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some help to fix this issue which I want to share in case anyone has a similar problem. Firstly the .ai files are taking so long because of the detailed resolution set out in my settings, reduce the resolution and they are created faster. Secondly, the Psd files are being created as they are because I'm appending them using the Horizontal method. When I changed my code to the code below it worked.

```
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    images.Read(file, settings);
    images.Write(path + "\\" + ThumbnailFolder + "\\TempThumb.png");                                               
}
```